# How can Visual Studio use boost::function with /GR- while GCC can't with -fno-rtti?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, android-ndk

I recently started porting an application to Android using the NDK and I encountered the following error:

```
boost/function/function_base.hpp:220: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti.
```

Ordinarily, I wouldn't think twice about that error, but the visual studio project file set `/GR-`, which disables RTTI and has no problem using boost::function.

My theory on this is that because typeid is evaulated by the compilier when the static type can be determined, that must be the case for every usage of boost::function in the application.  Visual Studio must be attempting to determine the static type first while GCC immediately throws the error on typeid before attempting to evaluate it.

Does that sound right?  If not, what is going on?

Comment: Is BOOST_NO_TYPEID defined consistently between the two different compilers?

Comment: Why are you even trying?

Comment: @selbie It is not defined in either case.  I took a look in function.hpp and function/function_base.hpp and neither check for that symbol.  I tried adding it and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @wilx I'm sure I will be turning on RTTI, I am trying to understand why Visual Studio doesn't need it.

Comment: Sounds right. Note that "no RTTI" already means "not C++ anymore", so compilers are free to do whatever they like. In particular, you can't expect two compilers to behave identically anymore, as you eliminated the one reason they do (the ISO standard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not booted into my Windows partition, but it was just as simple to look this up in MSDN.

As per [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> If the expression is dereferencing a pointer, and that pointer's value
>   is zero, typeid throws a bad_typeid exception. If the pointer does not
>   point to a valid object, a __non_rtti_object exception is thrown,
>   indicating an attempt to analyze the RTTI that triggered a fault (like
>   access violation), because the object is somehow invalid (bad pointer
>   **or the code wasn't compiled with /GR**).
>
> If the expression is neither a pointer nor a reference to a base class
>   of the object, the result is a type_info reference representing the
>   static type of the expression. The static type of an expression refers
>   to the type of an expression as it is known **at compile time**.....

In other words, if the expression's type can't be inferred at compile time, and no /GR, then you're going to get an exception or compiler error.  But the second paragraph kind of implies it can infer non-ambiguous types at compile time.

Comment: As a point of clarification, do you agree with what I said in the question about GCC generating the error before attempting to do this?

Comment: Your theory is consistent with what MSDN hints at.